# If only one Matrix block show this, for more then one block show that

Tags: matrix, conditional

I have a Matrix field which contains a bunch of blocks. If only one matrix field is present in the entry I need it to show a message. If more then one matrix field show an other message.

Below is my current code.

```
{% for block in entry.modelIds.limit(1) %}
    {% if block.modelId|length == 1 %}
        I am link - {{block.modelId}} <br>
    {% else %}
        Not a Link - {{block.modelId}}<br>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried a few different approaches and am just stumped.

Thanks!

Edit: adding image of fields.
[image]

Comment: "If only one matrix field is present" Do you mean "matrix block" there? I assume `modelIds` is the Matrix field, what type of field is `modelId`?

Comment: modelIds is the matrix field name.  block.modelId is a plain text field within modelIds. I hope this helps.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong: if a Matrix block has 1 field show message A, if it has more than one field show message B?

Comment: That is/was correct. Now that I am thinking about it, what I want to check for is if there is only one modelIds per entry not individual modelId. I need to update my example code! Thanks for helping me figure out that I was testing for the wrong element. Update coming soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Brad for asking me a question above, it made me realize I was checking for matrix fields and not the matrix block. My code is now working that I am checking for the correct element on the page.

Revised code:

```
{% if entry.modelIds|length == 1 %}
     I am link - {{block.modelId}} <br>
{% else %}
     Not a Link - {{block.modelId}}<br>
{% endif %}
```

Thanks Brad for the help!